# Using a constant for a UIImageView name

Tags: ios, swift

I have a button and 5 UIImageView on my application. UIImageViews names are ECard1, ECard2, ECard3 ....

I would like that when I press the button, a random card is selected and shown in the next UIImageViewer. But I can't automatically increase UIImageView name in code. I tried this:

```
ECard1.image = UIImage (named: Ekartlar[0])
var cardno = 1
cardno = cardno + 1
var cardname = "ECard"
var viewername = cardname + string(cardno)
viewername.image = UIImage (named: Ekartlar[1]) -- I can't use like that
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You need to store your five image views instances in an array and refer to it with an index.

Comment: @user523234 can u tell me how is it syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Just put the image views into an array and access the appropriate view through its index.

```
let ECard1 = UIImageView()
let ECard2 = UIImageView()
let ECard3 = UIImageView()
let ECard4 = UIImageView()
let ECard5 = UIImageView()

let imageViews = [ECard1, ECard2, ECard3, ECard4, ECard5]

var cardno = 1
imageViews[cardno].image = UIImage(named: "foo")
```

Comment: But i had this error : Invalid redeclaration of ECard1 (for all of cards)

Comment: @Bronson The first 5 lines of the snippet in my answer were just meant for demonstration. You don't need them in your actual code because these variables already exist.

Comment: This time i had this error; Instance member 'ECard1' cannot be used on type 'ViewController'

Comment: @Bronson Where exactly did you put the code to create the array? Are the image view variables accessible in that place? It might help if you shared more code by editing your question.

Comment: @Bronson Just edit your question and append whatever code you have now.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach is to assign unique tags to the `UIImageView` instances in Interface Builder for example starting with 101 for an 1-based index. Then you can access the image views with

```
var cardno = 1
let imageView = view.viewWithTag(cardno + 100) as! UIImageView
```